# ¿Que pasa con las solicitudes consumidas por node que comparten una variable de ambito global?

Tags: nodejs, variables-globales

Imaginemos que tengo el siguiente código escrito en `nodejs`:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

var my_global_var = [];

app.get('/addvalue', function(req, resp, next) {
    var new_value = req.query.new_value;
    
    my_global_var[my_global_var.length] = new_value;
    
    resp.send("La variable ha sido escrita.");
});

app.get('/getvalues', function(req, resp, next) {
    resp.send("La variable 'my_global_var' es '" + (JSON.stringify(my_global_var)) + "'");
});

http.listen(3001);
```

Es posible que `node` reciba peticiones concurrentes?

Es decir, si se hicieran varias de peticiones exactamente al mismo tiempo (en el mismo instante) a la dirección `http://*:3001/addvalue`, ¿Cómo se escribiría la variable `my_global_var`?

Lo pregunto porque tengo entendido que `node` trabaja como **mono-hilo no bloqueante**, y mucho del contenido que existe habla de la **asincronía** de `node`, pero cuando existen `callbacks` que comparten la escritura de una misma variable, ¿Cómo trata `node` esta situación?, ¿A caso existe un bloqueo al escribir una misma variable? o ¿Al ser el manejo de eventos totalmente asíncrono se escribe la misma posición del arreglo (en este caso el indice 0)?

Hay mucha documentación sobre la **asincronía**, pero ningún ejemplo de **variables compartidas**...

Comment: Respondo porque me parece un tema interesante ... pero la pregunta en sí es poco clara y **demasiado amplia**. Aún se podría hablar de muchos detalles sobre como Node interrumpe una operación de E/S ... Sinceramente, a mi juicio, se merece un voto de cierre :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Es posible que node reciba peticiones concurrentes?

## No.

Las peticiones, antes de llegar a Node, son procesadas por el Sistema Operativo, que **las coloca en una cola**. Aun suponiendo que tuviéramos varias interfaces de red, y que realmente varias peticiones llegaran exactamente a la vez, el propio Sistema Operativo las encolaría de forma secuencial (aproximadamente en el orden de llegada). Si la cola estuviera llena, la petición se descarta. El protocolo TCP se encarga del resto, avisando de paquetes perdidos, y las máquinas origen reenvían los paquetes y ajustan automáticamente la velocidad de envío. Todo esto ocurre **antes de que Node reciba la petición**.

En cualquier caso, Node se limita a sacar eventos de la cola **de 1 en 1**. El cómo los eventos han sido colocados ahí, y el orden en el que se han producido y encolado es irrelevante.

> tengo entendido que node trabaja como mono-hilo no bloqueante

## ... A nivel de *socket*.

El concepto de  *hilo* no admite el calificativo de `no-bloqueante`. Un hilo solo puede estar en 2 estados: ocupando tiempo de CPU (en ejecución) o no ocupándolo (pausado, suspendido).

En esa expresión, `no bloqueante` se refiere **al trabajo con sockets**. Estas abstracciones, a nivel de Sistema Operativo, pueden trabajar en 2 modos:

- Bloqueante: el hilo realiza una solicitud al Sistema Operativo. Este **suspende** el hilo hasta que dicha solicitud se finalice. El hilo no puede hacer absolutamente nada mas que esperar hasta que la solicitud se complete.
- No bloqueante: el hilo realiza una solicitud al Sistema Operativo. Este la procesa y realiza **en segundo plano**. El hilo solicitante puede seguir realizando otras tareas: cálculos e incluso otras peticiones bloqueantes y no bloqueantes (si, se pueden mezclar). El sistema Operativo genera eventos con los cambios de estado de las tareas solicitadas (finalización, errores). El hilo comprueba peridicamente si tiene nuevos eventos y actúa en consecuencia. Incluso puede suspenderse a si mismo hasta que tenga nuevos eventos pendientes.

Por lo tanto, la frase completa sería `Node trabaja en moni-hilo, usando operaciones de Entrada/Salida no bloqueantes`.

> cuando existen callbacks que comparten la escritura de una misma variable, como trata node esta situación?

## Las instrucciones de JavaScript son atómicas.

El modelo de eventos de JavaScript (y por extensión el de Node) es muy simple: usa el [patrón reactor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) (que, cosas de la vida, se ajusta perfectamente al trabajo con sockets no-bloqueantes):

1. Se espera a que existan eventos en la cola.
2. Se extrae uno de ellos.
3. Se procesa **todo el código JavaScript asociado**, hasta llegar al último `return`.

Eso quiere decir que, en un momento dado, solo puede existir una instrucción de JavaScript en ejecución. En otras palabras, la ejecución puede estar en un punto cualquiera del programa ... pero **solo en 1 punto**. En tu código, en un momento dado cualquiera, se estará ejecutando código del `get( '/addvalue' )` o del `get( '/getvalues' )`. Por lo tanto, tu instrucción

```
my_global_var[my_global_var.length] = new_value;
```

desde el punto de vista de Node y de JavaScript, se ejecutará siempre **de forma atómica**. No es posible corromper esa variable ni dejarla en estado inconsistente.

Como último apunte: las llamadas `setTimeout( )` y `setInterval( )` **se limitan a colocar un evento en la cola** (mas o menos). Su ejecución es muy rápida, y no rompen el modelo de eventos: no esperan a que pase el tiempo, sino que generan un evento `ejecutar código` que será procesado cuando le llegue el turno, como todos los demás.

## Asincronía, *callbacks*, Entrada/Salida no bloqueante ... ¡ Menuda mezcla !

Esto es simple conceptualmente, pero realmente complejo a bajo nivel.

Al llamar a determinadas instrucciones (`write( )`, por ejemplo), dicha llamada provoca que **toda la pila de llamadas y variables** de JavaScript se guarde en memoria, y se suspenda la ejecución asociada. Es una especie de *simulación* de multitarea. Esto se conoce por varios nombres: `hilos ligeros`, `hilos a nivel de usuario`, y algún nombre mas.

Ahora ya se puede ver mas claro como trabaja realmente Node: cada evento interno **lleva asociada una referencia a la pila implicada**. Node extrae un evento de la cola, *descongela* la pila asociada, y continua su ejecución por el punto en el que quedó. Esa es su *magia*.

Con lo que ya sabemos, ahora tu pregunta puede extenderse un poco mas:

> ¿ Que pasa si una operación de Entrada/Salida queda bloqueada y otra función modifica una variable necesaria para esa Entrada/Salida ?

En tu ejemplo, supongamos que llega un momento en que tu variable `my_global_var` llega a tener varios millones de elementos. Enviar esa cantidad de datos requiere cierta cantidad de tiempo ... sobre todo si la red está saturada.

¿ Sería posible modificar esa variable **antes de enviarla por completo** ?

Node soluciona este problema de una forma muy sencilla, que tu ya usas en tu código:

```
JSON.stringify( my_global_var )
```

Ahí está el truco. El envío de los datos tardará mas o menos tiempo ... pero la ejecución de `stringify( )` **es atómica**. Lo que tu estás enviando **no es tu variable `my_global_var`**, sino **una representación en formato de texto** generada a partir de la variable en un momento dado. Y esa generación **es atómica**, por lo que no es posible modificar la variable en mitad de esa generación.

Como dicen en mi pueblo, `hecha la ley, hecha la trampa`. Conociendo este *truco*, nos surgen nuevas preguntas:

> ¿ Y si envío una gran cantidad de datos **que ya están en formato texto** ?

Aquí entra en juego las características del propio lenguaje. Las cadenas de texto son **inmutables**. Si intentas enviar directamente una cadena ... pues **se realiza una copia de la misma**. Recordemos que, en JavaScript, el paso de valores inmutables como argumentos implica su copia. Copia que se realiza **de forma atómica**. Por lo tanto, aunque modifiques la cadena original, la copia ya estará hecha y no habrá consecuencias. Es una versión *automágica* de lo visto anteriormente: no envías el dato, sino una representación del mismo.

> ¿ Y si hago uso de funciones que **si soportan** el envío de datos complejos (mutables) ?

Sobre este caso, no he encontrado información disponible. Así que no nos quedará mas remedio que comprobarlo por nosotros mismos. Acudimos a la mejor fuente de información autorizada: la documentación de Node: [API for Stream Implementers](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementers)

> ## writable._write( chunk, encoding, callback )
>
> All Writable stream implementations must provide a `writable._write( )` method to send data to the underlying resource.

Vamos a simular al mas bajo nivel posible el comportamiento de una red saturada. Para ello, nos crearemos nuestro propio *stream*. Y esa es la función clave a implementar ... así que manos a la obra: Nos fabricaremos un *stream* que sea muy lento en el consumo de datos, y observamos lo que pasa si modificamos datos en mitad de su consumición:

```
const Streams = require( 'stream' );
const { Buffer } = require( 'buffer' );

var data = Buffer.from( 'a'.repeat( 10000000 ) );
var slowStream;

class SlowStream extends Streams.Writable {
  constructor( options ) {
    super( options );
  }
  _write( chunk, encoding, callback ) {
    console.log( 'Length:', chunk.length, 'First char:', chunk[0] );

    setTimeout( function( ) {
      callback( null );
    }, 300 );
  }
}

slowStream = new SlowStream( );

setTimeout( function( ) {
  console.log( 'Fill data with <b>' );
  data.fill( 'b' );
}, 400 );

console.log( 'Start writing' );
slowStream.write( data );
```

Para mi sorpresa, el resultado fue:

> Start writing
>   Length: 10000000 First char: 97
>   Fill data with <b>

La primera en la frente. Yo esperaba que Node *troceara* el `chunk` de alguna forma, basándose en el tamaño de algún *buffer* interno o algo ... pero no, la función lo recibe *tal cual*.

Bueno, no pasa nada. Eliminamos el `setTimeout( )` y hacemos algunos otros cambios menores:

```
const Streams = require( 'stream' );
const { Buffer } = require( 'buffer' );

var data = Buffer.from( 'a'.repeat( 50000000 ) );
var slowStream;

class SlowStream extends Streams.Writable {
  constructor( options ) {
    super( options );
  }
  _write( chunk, encoding, callback ) {
    console.log( 'Enter:', chunk.length, 'First char:', chunk[0] );

    setTimeout( function( ) {
      console.log( 'Leave:', chunk.length, 'First char:', chunk[0] );
      callback( null );
    }, 300 );
  }
}

slowStream = new SlowStream( );

console.log( 'Start writing' );
slowStream.write( data );
console.log( 'Fill data with <b>' );
data.fill( 'b' );
```

Con estos cambios, la salida fue:

> Start writing
>   Enter: 50000000 First char: 97
>   Fill data with <b>
>   Leave: 50000000 First char: 98

## ¡¡ El objeto *mutable* puede ser modificado en mitad de la operación !!

## ¡¡ Es posible corromper a nivel lógico un dato compartido !!

Bueno, pues terminamos ya. En resumen:

- Node usa el patrón Reactor: saca eventos de una cola, procesa todo el código JavaScript asociado, y continua con el siguiente evento.
- Puesto que se ejecuta todo el código, cualquier modificación en un dato es atómica: no se puede interrumpir y dejar un dato *corrupto* a bajo nivel.
- El Sistema Operativo garantiza que, aun recibiendo múltiples peticiones simultáneas, estás se encolaran de 1 en 1, en el orden aproximado en el que se reciben.
- Node normalmente no envía datos, sino representaciones de los datos en un momento dado.
- Si se envían datos inmutables, JavaScript los copia al pasarlos como argumento. Modificaciones del original no afectan.
- Si se envían datos mutables y el envío es interrumpido, es posible corromper a nivel lógico los datos.
- Cada implementación de un `Stream.Writable` es responsable del manejo de los datos si estos son mutables: pueden copiarlos, generar una representación, ... o enviar datos incorrectos.

## Postdata

Para objetos *mutables*, el lenguaje detalla ciertos comportamientos:

#### [Array.forEach( )](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach):

> El rango de elementos procesados por `forEach( )` se establece antes de la primera invocación del *callback*. Los elementos que sean añadidos al vector después de que inicie la llamada a `forEach( )` no serán visitados por *callback*. Si los valores de los elementos existentes en el vector son modificados, el valor pasado al *callback* será el valor al momento de que `forEach( )` los visite; no se evaluarán los elementos borrados antes de ser visitados por `forEach.( )`.

#### [Bucle `for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in):

> Un bucle `for ... in` recorre las propiedades de un objeto con orden arbitrario. Si una propiedad se modifica en una iteración y luego se vuelve a visitar, el valor final de la propiedad será el de la última visita. Una propiedad que se borre antes de ser visitada no será visitada más tarde. Las propiedades que se añadan al objeto en la iteración que está teniendo lugar, pueden ser tanto visitadas como omitidas en la iteración. En general, lo mejor es no añadir, modificar o borrar propiedades del objeto mientras dure la iteración sobre él, salvo sean propiedades del objeto que actualmente se está visitando en la iteración; no existen garantías sobre que una propiedad añadida vaya a ser visitada, ni de si una propiedad modificada va a ser visitada antes de que sea modificada o después, ni siquiera de que si una propiedad es borrada vaya a ser visitada antes de borrarse o después.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, hay detalles de NodeJS en esta respuesta que normalmente paso por alto, pero aquí están bastante bien definidos. +1.